# Using changePage in JQuery Mobile in Cordova (PhoneGap)

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have downloaded the file structure of my JQuery Mobile app. I have done this to test running it from the local file system. The reason why is I want my app to run with Cordova. From my understanding cordova runs files under file://. Currently, my file structure looks like this:

```
index.html
account
  register.html
  reset.html
```

In index.html, I have a "sign up" button. When someone clicks it, I use the following code:

```
$.mobile.changePage("account/register.html", { transition: "slide" });
```

I've verified that register.html works fine if i put the complete path in the browser url.  Oddly, I see "error loading page" when I click "sign up". Is there some problem with using changePage under file://. If so, how do I overcome this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$.mobile.changePage("../account/register.html", { transition: "slide" });
```

Comment: how does this solve anything? What is the "current directory" while showing index.html in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can just leave `<a href="">..</a>` links in the code and it will work fine. Unless you have a reason to explicitly call changePage.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specificly if you run into an issue running the PhoneGap app on iOS.

Be sure you set the `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;` which is required for AJAX calls to inject pages.

In your PhoneGap `app` object definition:

```js
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        // setting required to use $.mobile.changePage()
        // http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    },
};
```

So when you call `app.initialize()` in your `index.html`, this property will be set prior to any `$.mobile.changePage()` function calls.

This will save you hours of trying to figure out the issue as no error is returned via the Safari Web Inspector.